# Как реализовать вывод результат в три колонки в GUI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
import requests
import csv
from lxml import etree
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
from random import randint
from time import sleep
from functools import reduce


headers = {'User-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0"}

def get_by_name(name):
    url = 'https://rozetka.com.ua/search/?section_id=&section=&text='+ name

    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers,timeout=10)

    tree = etree.HTML(r.text)

    links = [tag.get('href') for tag in tree.cssselect('.g-i-tile-i-title a')]

    return links

def get_product_info(url):
    data = dict()
    try:
        r = requests.get(url, headers=headers,timeout=10)
    except:
        return {}
    tree = etree.HTML(r.text)

    sleep(randint(1,3))
    print(url)

    data['Cсылка'] = r.url
    data['Название'] = tree.cssselect('h1')[0].text.strip()

    try:
        data['Цена'] = re.findall('productPriceLocal":"([0-9]{1,})',r.text)[0]
    except:
        try:
            data['Цена'] = ''.join(tree.cssselect('detail-price-uah')[0].itertext())
        except Exception as msg:
            print(msg)

    return data

def data_to_text(data):
    txt = u""

    txt += u'Название|цена|ссылка\n'
    txt += reduce(lambda a,x: a+x, [u'|'.join(value.values())+u'\n' for value in data], u'')

    return txt

def parse_function(product_links):
    products_data = []

    pool = ThreadPool(8)
    data = pool.map(get_product_info, product_links)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    products_data += data

    return products_data

    keys = products_data[0].keys()
    with open('products_data.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as f:
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(f, keys)
        dict_writer.writeheader()
        dict_writer.writerows(products_data)


class ParserGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Rozetka")
        master.geometry('850x500')


        self.greet_button = Button(master, text="Найти товары", command=self.greet)
        self.greet_button.pack()

        self.label = Label(master, text="Введите текст поиска")
        self.label.pack()

        self.txt = Entry(master,width=10)
        self.txt.pack()

        self.close_button = Button(master, text="Выход", command=master.quit)
        self.close_button.pack()

        self.label2 = Label(master, text="Результат:")
        self.label2.pack()

        self.S = Scrollbar(master)
        self.T = Text(master,height=master.cget('height'))
        self.S.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        self.T.pack(expand=True,side=TOP, fill='both')

        self.S.config(command=self.T.yview)

    def set_input(self,value):

        self.T.insert(1.0, value)

    def greet(self):
        print("Start!")

        txt = self.txt.get()

        try:
            links = get_by_name(txt)
        except Exception as msg:
            print(msg)
            messagebox.showinfo('Результат','Rozetka недоступна')

        data = parse_function(links)

        rez = data_to_text(data)

        self.set_input(rez)

        messagebox.showinfo('Результат','Информация найдена!')


def main():
    root = Tk()
    my_gui = ParserGUI(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Куда? В консоль, в файл, в GUI? Напишите подробнее в вопрос (кнопка `править`)

Comment: @gil9red Результат в  GUI

Comment: Тогда, добавляйте соответствующую метку, чтобы вопрос было проще найти людям в теме. Кст, смотрю у вас уже есть код для подобного в data_to_text. Вам достаточно будет вывести результат как текст или нужен именно виджет таблица?

Comment: @gil9red Да нужно в таблице , что бы цена , ссылка , название . Были в разных колонках.

Answer (score 0):

Решил развить первоначальную идею автора с таблицей в виде текста и вот что вышло:

- Добавляем функцию [print_pretty_table](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/76bb4cfa139ff14c319f836f4cf78985608b2bc8/ascii_table__simple_pretty__rjust.py#L7)
- Меняем функцию data_to_text
- Меняем `ParserGUI/__init__`

```
...

def print_pretty_table(data, cell_sep=' | ', header_separator=True):
    rows = len(data)
    cols = len(data[0])

    col_width = []
    for col in range(cols):
        columns = [data[row][col] for row in range(rows)]
        col_width.append(len(max(columns, key=len)))

    separator = "-+-".join('-' * n for n in col_width)

    lines = []

    for i, row in enumerate(range(rows)):
        if i == 1 and header_separator:
            lines.append(separator)

        result = []
        for col in range(cols):
            item = data[row][col].rjust(col_width[col])
            result.append(item)

        lines.append(cell_sep.join(result))

    return '\n'.join(lines)

def data_to_text(data):
    rows = [(x['Название'], x['Цена'], x['Ссылка']) for x in data]
    return print_pretty_table([("НАЗВАНИЕ", "ЦЕНА", "ССЫЛКА")] + rows)

...

class ParserGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Rozetka")
        master.geometry('850x500')

        self.greet_button = Button(master, text="Найти товары", command=self.greet)
        self.greet_button.pack()

        self.label = Label(master, text="Введите текст поиска")
        self.label.pack()

        self.txt = Entry(master,width=10)
        self.txt.pack()

        self.close_button = Button(master, text="Выход", command=master.quit)
        self.close_button.pack()

        self.label2 = Label(master, text="Результат:")
        self.label2.pack()

        frame = Frame()
        sy = Scrollbar(frame)
        sx = Scrollbar(frame,  orient=HORIZONTAL)
        self.T = Text(frame, height=500, width=300, wrap='none', xscrollcommand=sx.set, yscrollcommand=sy.set)
        sx.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
        sy.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        self.T.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
        sy.config(command=self.T.yview)
        sx.config(command=self.T.xview)
        frame.pack()
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: При компиляции выдает ошибку .Вот ссылка на скрин http://priscree.ru/img/b8f793cb6c265c.png

Comment: @Chaplin_here, а, блин, забыл... У вас "Ссылка" написано с первой буквой из латиницы, что я исправил, а написать забыл. Поэтому поменяйте ваши `Cсылка` на `Ссылка`. А так, в следующий раз просто напишите текстом текст исключения. Наверняка там KeyError. А так, я не могу посмотреть скриншот -- прокси на работе не пускает

Comment: KeyError: 'Название' Вот такая ошибка, а когда с впн то KeyError: 'Цена'

Comment: @Chaplin_here, фигня какая-то, ключ 'Название' и в моем коде, и в вашем (из вопроса) одинаково, да и по вашему коду 'Название' всегда будет заполняться. А насчет 'Цена', у вас она может не существовать и этому будет предшествовать исключение в консоли, поэтому добавьте в get_product_info строчку `data['Цена'] = ''`